# "SASLprep" profile of the "stringprep" implementation in c++

Tags: c++, windows, pdf, encryption, aes

I am implementing AES 256 bit encryption in PDF and PDF reference manual states first step of Algorithm 3.2a for Computing an encryption key

**1. The password string is generated from Unicode input by processing the input string with the SASLprep
(IETF RFC 4013) profile of stringprep (IETF RFC 3454), and then converting to a UTF-8 representation.**

My question is how to convert string to string prep?. Is there any free library for windows to perform SASLprep profile of string prep, i have found library for Unix but not for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://www.gnu.org/software/libidn.
It specifies that there is a windows solution (visual studio).
This proved to be false for all 2.x versions, but 1.17 has a win32 directory with just the right stuff for visual studio C++. You need to set some defines, at least LIBIDN_BUILDING, and LIBIDN_STATIC for a, you guessed it, static library as opposed to a dll. I got all versions to compile (and link if applicable) with very few warnings (only some pointer subtraction -> long), using VS2019.
SASL(prep) is included.
If desired, you can check if the newer versions can be done by replacing the source files with newer. Tell us if you do.